# Getting a minidom XML child node value safely

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am using Python and minidom for the first time and want to get a value from an element something like:

```
<test>value</test>
```

This is fine and straightforward, but if the value is empty or the element does not exist then I want to fall back to a default. I could find no simple way to do this in Python so I ended up writing the following function:

```
def getXmlValue(address, default):
   """Return XML node value if available, otherwise return a default"""

   # If the xml element is empty then we get an IndexError exception,
   # if the xml element is missing then the 'if' statement is false
   if address:
      try:
         return address[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
      except IndexError:
         return default

   return default
```

To call this I use something like:

```
test = getXmlValue(node.getElementsByTagName('test'), '666')
```

This does the job and seems to work fine, but doesn't seem all that efficient or elegant.

Is there a better way to do this or is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: That looks to be a perfectly reasonable way of getting the value without an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ElementTree` it should be much easier.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, fromstring

xml = '<test>value</test>'
root = fromstring(xml)
test = root.text or '666'
```

Answer (score 0):

since *childNodes* is going to be an array, how about just doing a length check and deciding otherwise. in some of my code I have something like below. If the childNode.length > 0 then I assign a the childNode[0] data otherwise just an empty string.

```
                my_element = alertitem.getElementsByTagName('solution')[0]
                result.mydata= my_element.childNodes[0].data if my_element.childNodes.length > 0 else ''
```

to me, seems better than a try except.